# Gradle - Recursive subprojects

Tags: gradle, multi-project

Assume I wanted to use `Gradle` with a project structure such as:

```
RootProject
\-- SubProjectA
    \-- SubProjectAA
    \-- SubProjectAB
```

How I would I achieve this?

What I tried is pretty straightforward. I've created all directories, with a structure described above:

```
RootProject
\-- SubProjectA
    \-- SubProjectAA
        \-- build.gradle
    \-- SubProjectAB
        \-- build.gradle
    \-- build.gradle
    \-- settings.gradle
\-- build.gradle
\-- settings.gradle
```

RootProject/settings.gradle:

```
include "SubProjectA"
```

RootProject/SubProjectA/settings.gradle:

```
include "SubProjectAA", "SubProjectAB"
```

There are two things I tried. First, I tried importing the project in Eclipse - which didn't detect `SubProjectAA` nor `SubProjectAB`. Stunned, I ran `gradle projects` in `RootProject` and got this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'RootProject'
\--- Project ':SubProjectA'
```

Still, thinking I made a mistake, I tried running the same command in SubProjectA, and got:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'RootProject'
\--- Project ':SubProjectAA'
\--- Project ':SubProjectAB'
```

I assume that resolving subprojects doesn't go recursively. Is there any workaround for this?

Every example is masked with sample names, sorry if I made any mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can only have one `settings.gradle`. Typically it would contain something like:

```
include "SubProjectA:SubProjectAA"
include "SubProjectA:SubProjectAB"
```

More information can be found in the "multi-project builds" chapter of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification here. Do you know if there is any movement on this? I find this pretty fiddly for bigger projects. I have seen this issue but no additional comments: [link](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1559)

Comment: how do you write the dependency for SubProjectAA then?

Answer (score -2):

try with

```
RootProject
\-- SubProjectA
    \-- SubProjectAA
        \-- build.gradle
    \-- SubProjectAB
        \-- build.gradle
\-- build.gradle
\-- settings.gradle

include ':SubProjectA/SubProjectAA'
```